# How to display a unique string message based off of index position and value of an ArrayList Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-structures, error-handling

I have a bunch of integers in an ArrayList. The values are either 1 or 0 at any given time. I have a unique string error message that I would like to display for each of these items if any of the values switch to 1. I have a single textView where I would like to display the current error message if there is one.

For some reason, I cannot understand how to do this. Is there a data structure that I can leverage to solve this problem efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an anonymous subclass of ArrayList or LinkedList that overrides the `set` function to do some action whenever a value is changed:

```
val myList = object: ArrayList<Int>() {
    override fun set(index: Int, element: Int): Int {
        return super.set(index, element).also { previousElement ->
            if (previousElement == 0 && element == 1) {
                showErrorMessageForIndex(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
// where showErrorMessageForIndex is a function that sets a message on your text view.
```

If you do this kind of thing in multiple places in your app, you can generalize it into a reusable class like this:

```
class MyArrayList<T>(
    val onValueChange: (index: Int, oldValue: T, newValue: T)-> Unit
): ArrayList<T>() {
    override fun set(index: Int, element: T): T {
        return super.set(index, element).also { previousElement ->
            if (previousElement != element) {
                onValueChange(index, previousElement, element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you create the list, use:

```
val myList = MyArrayList<Int> { index, oldValue, newValue ->
    if (oldValue == 0 && newValue == 1) {
        showErrorMessageForIndex(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting answer. I will give it a shot tomorrow and see how it goes.